# .htaccess re-direct rule not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

okay so i have this .htaccess file and i have other file called goto.php

.htaccess 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ goto.php?url=$1 [L]`

and the goto.php file :

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
die($url);
?>
```

the problem is when i go to this link : http://website.com/test/anything_here
i should get anything_here printed ?
how can i fix this ?
and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **capture** the data you want: `([^/]+)` instead of `[^/]+`
Otherwise, `$1` is empty.

Assuming your htaccess and `goto.php` files are both in `test` folder, replace your current code by this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ goto.php?url=$1 [L]
```